# Problems uploading file with special characters

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a code in which I strip the file name's special characters (á, é, ñ, ...) and then I upload the file:

```
$new_name = gen_new_name($_FILES['document']['name'], $ext_doc);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['documento_'.$a]["tmp_name"], "../soportes/".$new_name);

function gen_new_name($file, $extension) {
    $file_2 = stripAccents($file);
    $file_2 = str_replace(' ', '_', $file_2);
    $file_2 = preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/', '_', $file_2);
    $file_2 = basename($file_2, ".".$extension);

    $new_name = mt_rand().'_'.$file_2.'.'.$extension;
    return $new_name;
}
function stripAccents($string) {
    $accents = array('À','Á','Â','Ã','Ä','Å','Æ','Ç','È','É','Ê','Ë','Ì','Í','Î','Ï','Ð','Ñ','Ò','Ó','Ô','Õ','Ö','Ø','Ù','Ú','Û','Ü','Ý','Þ','ß','à','á','â','ã','ä','å','æ','ç','è','é','ê','ë','ì','í','î','ï','ð','ñ','ò','ó','ô','õ','ö','ø','ù','ú','û','ý','ý','þ','ÿ','Ŕ','ŕ');
    $string = str_replace($accents, '', $string);
    return $string;
}
```

The html file I'm working with has `<meta charset="utf-8">` and I include the file with the function inside the body tag.

Everything seems to work ok, the issue is that when it uploads the file, I check that the name of the file indeed is changed throught the gen_new_name() function and echo the new file and it shows the name without the special characters and the random number at the start but when it uploads it also shows the random number in the beggining but the special characters are transformed to squares with a question mark inside and other ones.

If anyone knows how can I upload the file with the exact new name I would really apreciate it...Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry my code is in spanish, I missed transalating that variable....

Comment: This might not work - but it's worth trying.  On the <form> element try putting in a `accept-charset='UTF-8'`

Comment: No, it didn't work...but thanks